# How to change class name of <i> element on click which calls two functions?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I am new in javascript. I have created a click to copy button. It should **show the check icon after click on the button**. The code for **"copy function"** works well but **the code to change icon after click event did not work**.

There will be multiple copy buttons and each has unique ID attribute. I want to change the **"Copy icon"** to **"Check icon"** after clicked. I think the simple way is to change the class name in

`<i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest1"></i>`

from (class="far fa-copy") to (class="fas fa-check"), but the problem is the `changeClass` function does not understand which  class of the clicked button to change the class. The code changed the class of all  elements.

Also can I combine 2 functions `copyToClipboard(elementId)` and `changeClass()` into 1 function?

My website could not run with jQuery and I do not know what happen, I am newbie.

Thank you so much for your help.

```js
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
 var aux = document.createElement("input");
 aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
 document.body.appendChild(aux);
 aux.select();
 document.execCommand("copy");
 document.body.removeChild(aux);
}

function changeClass(elementId) {
 var x = document.getElementById("elementId");
   x.className = "fas fa-check";
}
```

```css
.copybutton {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
padding: 12px 10px;
text-decoration: none !important;
background: #333333;
background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border: none;
transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.77,0,0.175,1);
}
.copybutton {
color:#ffffff;
}
.copybutton:hover {
background: #c2a693;
transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.77,0,0.175,1);
}
.copybutton:focus {
outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-KzZiKy0DWYsnwMF+X1DvQngQ2/FxF7MF3Ff72XcpuPs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Finding HTML Elements by Tag Name</h2>

<div id="main">
<p>This example test.</p>
</div>

<div>
<h6 class="copy">Button 1: test 1 <span id="test1" style="display: none;">Test 1 copied</span> <button class="copybutton" onclick="copyToClipboard('test1');changeClass('classTest1')"><i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest1"></i></button></h6>
<h6 class="copy">Button 2: test 2 <span id="test2" style="display: none;">Test 2 copied</span> <button class="copybutton" onclick="copyToClipboard('test2');changeClass('classTest2')"><i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest2"></i></button></h6>
<p>Paste here: <input value="paste here for test copy function"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do that in two ways, the first like you did but I have changed the code, you can add as many `span` element to test, my code is dynamic don't worry

**Solution1**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Clipboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    button {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px 10px;
      background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 40%;
    }

    button:hover {
      background: #c2a693;
      transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.77,0,0.175,1);
    }

    button:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    span {
      display: none;
    }

    input {
      width: 200px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Finding HTML Elements by Tag Name</h2>
  <p>This example test.</p>

  <div id="container">
    <h6 >Button 1: test 1 <span>Test 1 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 2: test 2 <span>Test 2 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 3: test 3 <span>Test 3 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 4: test 4 <span>Test 4 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 5: test 5 <span>Test 5 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <p>Paste here: <input placeholder="paste here for test copy function"></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.querySelector("#container").onclick = function(e) { 
      if(e.target.nodeName === "I") {
        var tmpInput = document.createElement("input");
        document.body.appendChild(tmpInput);
        tmpInput.value = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText;
        tmpInput.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.querySelectorAll("i").forEach(function(element) {
          element.className = "fa fa-copy";
        });
        e.target.className = "fa fa-check";
        document.body.removeChild(tmpInput);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution2** *edited for 2 seconds timeout and selectors*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Clipboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    button {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 12px 10px;
      background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 40%;
    }

    button:hover {
      background: #c2a693;
      transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.77,0,0.175,1);
    }

    button:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    span {
      display: none;
    }

    input {
      width: 200px;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Finding HTML Elements by Tag Name</h2>
  <p>This example test.</p>

  <div id="container">
    <h6 >Button 1: test 1 <span>Test 1 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 2: test 2 <span>Test 2 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 3: test 3 <span>Test 3 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 4: test 4 <span>Test 4 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <h6 >Button 5: test 5 <span>Test 5 copied</span><button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></h6>
    <p>Paste here: <input placeholder="paste here for test copy function"></p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></button>
    <button><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i></button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var copiedText = "", clickedElement, currentTask;
    document.querySelector("#container").onclick = function(e) { 
      if(e.target.nodeName === "I") {
        copiedText = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerText;
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.querySelectorAll("#container i").forEach(function(element) {
          element.className = "fa fa-copy";
        });
        e.target.className = "fa fa-check";
        clickedElement = e.target;
      }
    }

    document.body.oncopy = function(e) {
      event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copiedText);
      event.preventDefault();
      clearTimeout(currentTask);
      currentTask = setTimeout(function() {
        clickedElement.className = "fa fa-copy";
      }, 2000);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's work perfectly with previousElementSibling code. I am finding the way to add a timeout function for change icon back to original Copy icon after 2 second or on moveout. Can you help me with it? Thank you so much

Comment: @sairy I have edited the second solution to change the last clicked element to it's original class after 2 seconds and I took care of when the user clicks on many elements one after another in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: It's work like a charm, perfect solution and easy understand code. Thank you so much

Comment: I just tried with my website and had problem. The code will find all <i> element and change the class after clicked and change them to class="fa fa-check". Example: if I have a text like this: <p>this test <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p> outside the "container" and some where on the page, they all change to <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>. I tried to fix it but had no luck. T.T

Comment: @sairy
Ah ok, I didn't know you are going to put my code into production, but if you want you need only to change some selectors, I have edited my post (Solution 2) to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution i can offer you this one

```
function someFunc(test, classTest) {
 copyToClipboard(test);
 changeClass(classTest);
}
```

And onclick add this function.

```
<h6 class="copy">Button 1: test 1 <span id="test1" style="display: none;">Test 1 copied</span> <button class="copybutton" onclick="someFunc('test1', 'classTest1')"><i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest1"></i></button></h6>
```

If you want to combine several functions for one element use `addEventListener('${action}', callbackFunction)` 
You can learn more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Also do not use same id for different elements, as you did for spans. Id always should be unique.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had mistake in IDs. I will review your link for more details although I start from 0 with Java T.T

Answer (score 0):

Your code can not work. First you have to use unique IDs in your HTML:

```
<h6 class="copy">Button 1: test 1 <span id="test1" style="display: none;">Test 1 copied</span> <button id="button2" class="copybutton" )"><i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest1"></i></button></h6>
<h6 class="copy">Button 2: test 2 <span id="test2" style="display: none;">Test 2 copied</span> <button id="button2" class="copybutton"><i class="far fa-copy" id="classTest2"></i></button></h6>
```

Of course you can combine different actions into one function call. For readability of your code and reusability keep different functions seperated and call them inthe clickevent. Example:

```
/* This ensures that all elements are in DOM = ready */
if (document.readyState!="loading") docReady();
/* Modern browsers */
else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docReady);
function docReady() {
   // Since both elements are the same except for the ids we do it in a loop
    for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {  
      var clickElement = "button" + i;
       document.getElementById(clickElement).addEventListener("click", function(event){  // This is the function which is called when the button is clicked
         copyToClipboard("test" + i); // since per button we want to hand over the related id
         changeClass("classTest"+i);
       });
     }
}

function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
 var aux = document.createElement("input");
 aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
 document.body.appendChild(aux);
 aux.select();
 document.execCommand("copy");
 document.body.removeChild(aux);
}

function changeClass(elementId) {
 var x = document.getElementById("elementId");
 x.className = "fas fa-check"; // look into classList.add/ classList.remove
}
```

I deliberatly extended your code according to your question (removing the double id bug in your html), of course there is room for improvement but hey you wrote working code yourself. So pat yourself on the back and be proud of your work.

Comment: Thank you for help me fix the IDs bugs, I copied and forgot to change the ID. I read again and again your post and still not know how to use your edited code into my buttons. Which I should write in onclick="" attribute? Also, can I set the timeout for changeClass function to change the Check icon to Copy icon again after clicked few seconds? Sorry for my English, I am not good in English.

Comment: Just replace the two html lines with mine. copy the code in between the script tags and it should run. You do not need to infest your html with onclick - this is done by my ready function. Just test it. timer is easy define a time var which is set when copy and after reaching the time reset the icon Either foit in your changeClass or better do a resetClass as a third function and call it after changeClass in my ready function. If my answer works mark it as accepted so other can learn too